# auto adjust button size to screensize?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I am new to android development and im trying to create and app with a grid menu, 
[Menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSJJJ.png)

I am trying to make them auto adjust according to screensize, i tried to use layout_weight but that didnt do anything. Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComponents"
android:background="@drawable/background2" >

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/content"
    android:id="@+id/btContent"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btBanner"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Overzichten"
    android:id="@+id/btCollection"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_collection"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btContent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btGroup"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Nieuws"
    android:id="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_news"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btGroup"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Agenda"
    android:id="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_agenda"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btlabel"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/FotoAlbums"
    android:id="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_photoalbum"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btMenuItem"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Banner"
    android:id="@+id/btBanner"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_banner"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btContent"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btGroup"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Groepen"
    android:id="@+id/btGroup"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_group"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btCollection"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/NieuwsBrieven"
    android:id="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_newsletter"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Label"
    android:id="@+id/btlabel"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_label"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Menu"
    android:id="@+id/btMenuItem"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65" />
```

How i thought i had to use PercentRelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="nl.drieo.soundwave.test.cms.MainComponents"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:orientation="vertical">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/content"
    android:id="@+id/btContent"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btBanner"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Overzichten"
    android:id="@+id/btCollection"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_collection"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btContent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btGroup"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Nieuws"
    android:id="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_news"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btGroup"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Agenda"
    android:id="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_agenda"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btlabel"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/FotoAlbums"
    android:id="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_photoalbum"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btMenuItem"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Banner"
    android:id="@+id/btBanner"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_banner"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btContent"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btGroup"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Groepen"
    android:id="@+id/btGroup"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_group"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btCollection"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/NieuwsBrieven"
    android:id="@+id/btNewsLetter"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_newsletter"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btNewsItem"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Label"
    android:id="@+id/btlabel"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_label"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btAgendaItem"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="@string/Menu"
    android:id="@+id/btMenuItem"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Dependencies currently:
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'

Comment: `i tried to use layout_weight but that didnt do anything.` Well, you are using a **RelativeLayout**, while weights only work in a **LinearLayout** (and derived containers)

Comment: Do you want the buttons to autoadujst? If you do so,from your XML it seems like you have to do it programmatically  by getting the width and height of the screen than adjust the buttons to it. Or you could use LinearLayout with weightSum ? You could look into this here :http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: Yes i am trying to auto adjust, i want to try to make it with XML cause its a pretty big application and having to code it in is gonna be hard work. When converting to LinearLayout all the buttons are under each other, and i cant move them next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` with `weightSUm`. Or you can use google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this library you can set `weight` and `heigh` of your views by percentage which is great because in all screen they look the same and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

and official documentation by Google https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

**UPDATE**

Try some like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btBanner"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCollection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btContent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btGroup"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Overzichten"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNewsItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btGroup"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btNewsLetter"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Nieuws"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAgendaItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btNewsItem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btlabel"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Agenda"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btAgendaItem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btMenuItem"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="FotoAlbums"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btBanner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btGroup"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btContent"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Banner"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btNewsLetter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btCollection"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Groepen"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNewsLetter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btNewsItem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="NieuwsBrieven"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btlabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btAgendaItem"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btMenuItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btPhotoAlbum"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

and add this line in your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I might be doing it wrong but when i add the PercenRelativeLayout, it created a gray box and says that buttons arent allowed to be in there.

Comment: Okay i did that but everything went full white?

Comment: You copy my code and not work? It is very strain because i test it before give you.

Comment: Yes i copied your code, and added the dependencie and i got a full white screen

Comment: in your gradle did you have other compiles i got these too  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

Comment: See question for my dependencies. hope you can read it, if not ask for a screenshot

Comment: hmm and when its goes to white screen in preview mode or when you start application?

Comment: wait, i deleted 1 dependencie and i showed buttons let me check further if i still trigger this error

Comment: I have found the issue, i was trying to implement swiping my listview that i create using an API, so i added a library, and deleted that just now and for some reason that fixed it. Thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try RecyclerView. Here is a nice tutorial to get you going for autofit. http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you for your response, like i said in a different response, this application is pretty big and i want to keep layout and code seperated (seperated as can be) so would rather have it in xml :)

Comment: But the way you are doing, is not the right approach for many items. It will not be memory efficient.

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for doing this in XML? or does it HAVE to be code?

Comment: Well, there is code for that. Not everything can be achieved by XML.